# How to use Vue bus data inside another components data?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have 2 sibling Vue components and I am emitting both their datas via bus to the root. But I do not know how to use that bus data inside a component.

Here is the bus data that is caught in the root.

```
bus.$on("send-topic", selectedTopic => this.selectedTopic = selectedTopic);
```

How do I use it in the example below to replace topic_id. Also this is an object so I'd need to drill down to the ID property. So something like `selectedTopic['id']`

**Component Example**

```
<script>
  import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'
  export default {
    components: { Multiselect },
    props: ['value', 'api-url', 'api-token'],
    data () {
      return {
        internalValue: this.value,
        options: []
      }
    },
    mounted(){
      axios.get( this.apiUrl + '/questions/businesses', {
          params: { 
            topic_id: 1, // This is where I need to use it //
            keywords: ['kitchen', 'paint'] 
          }, 
          headers: {
            'api-token': this.apiToken 
          }
        }).then(response => this.options = response.data);
      }
</script>
```

Comment: `bus.$on` does not have to be in the root. You can listen to bus events anywhere.

Comment: Thanks I've actually worked this one out.

Comment: your code example doesn't show a single emit or on method ?